# Azure Search: Prioritize closest exact match over others in a prefix search

Tags: azure, lucene, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I'm currently doing a prefix search with `Azure Cognitive Search` like so:

`docs?api-version=2019-05-06&search=Do*`

Suppose that my index contains `Dog`, `Big Dog`, and `Small Dog`. The result set seems to be sorted alphabetically by default and looks like:

```
Big Dog
Dog
Small Dog
```

How can I change my query string so that the closest exact match appears first and the rest is sorted alphabetically? Here's the output I want:

```
Dog
Big Dog
Small Dog
```

So, if the user types `D`, `Do`, or `Dog`, I want to show `Dog` first to help them short-circuit typing.

Answer (score 0):

The results are ordered according to a score. This, is the result of TFxIDF formula. In other words, the results are displayed according to which term is more relevant according to your documents.

Saying that, I believe you must use NGram in order to get the most relevant term.

more info:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what your exact document looks like? As Thiago mentioned Azure Cognitive Search returns a relevance score which shows the relative relevance of the entire document corresponding to the input query.

If your documents have only 1 matching field with the exact text you shared, it should return "Dog" with the highest score as it's more relevant to the query.